# ApplicationContext.xml cannot be found when starting Tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, jakarta-ee, m2eclipse

I searched more questions about this issue on SO e.g putting applicationContext to WEB-INF/classes or src/resources add WEB-INF to build path but none of them seems to work

Im using maven to buil my Java EE project and always gat

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
```

Heres my `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">

        <display-name>Java EE Application Example</display-name>

        <welcome-file-list>
                <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

        <context-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
                <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
                <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
                <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
                <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
                <param-value>1</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
                <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                        <param-value></param-value>
                </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <filter>
                <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
                <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Spring security filters -->

</web-app>
```

And heres `applicationContext.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

        <import resource="datasource-config.xml" />
        <import resource="webflow-config.xml" />        



</beans>
```

Both files are in `/src/webapp/WEB-INF/`
Im using tomcat 7.0

EDIT: my project structure screenshot [project stucture](http://clip2net.com/clip/m173788/1397207705-clip-19kb.png?nocache=1)
Any help will be appreciated

EDIT2:
heres my `pom.xml` file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.j2eeapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>j2eeapplication</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>J2EE Application Example</name>

  <repositories>
        <repository>
                <id>prime-repo</id>
                <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
                <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
                <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>20030825.184428</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.02</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: @Prasad i have edited post now pom.xml is included

Comment: Can you post project structure in Java enterprise perspective.

Comment: You do not have to put your applicationContext.xml on the classpath. `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` is the right place to put your  applicationContext.xml. Could you share your project's Deployment Assembly setting(Project's "Properties" -> "Deployment Assembly")? How do you run your application? ("Run As" -> "Run on Server" in eclipse?)

Comment: @ShinichiKai hi thanks for reply yes i run it as you mentioned Run As→Run On server before that i do maven build and maven install. Heres deployment assembly http://clip2net.com/s/7cXFrU

Comment: Your configuration seems correct. I am not sure what went wrong in your case, but cleaning your server is worth a try.(Right click your server -> "Clean")

Comment: @ShinichiKai Well it didnt work. What are the things i have to set up in my project besides these xml files to run spring ? If xml's are ok this can be the only thing left

Comment: Can you deploy the created war file with maven install to your  Tomcat's webapp directory?

Comment: If the created war file works correctly, this may be an Eclipse related issue. If this is the case, re-installing your Eclipse might solve your problem.

Comment: @ShinichiKai Ive tried Kepler and Juno with same result. I have maybe one last question . When changing in my web.xml file `<context-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>some/nonexisting/path.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>` aaplication still searches for /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml why is that ?

Comment: Seems that ContextLoaderListener does not recognize contextConfigLocation param (`/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` is the default location for the root application context.) or your Eclipse does not recognize changes in web.xml somehow. Sorry, I have no ideas what the cause of this problem is...

Comment: @Ziker are there any other spring projects deployed in Tomcat apart from this one?

Comment: @Prasad Well Im not sure but, I have two instances of Tomcat running one is service running on localhost:8080 that has zero projects deplyoed i only use it when deploying war file. And second is eclipse instance on localhost:8083 used obviously only for one project currently run in Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. I solved it moving the file `applicationContext.xml`in a sub-folder of the `src`folder. e.g:

```
context = newClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/com/example/rawfile/applicationContext.xml")
```

Comment: Im kinda new in this stuff. Where i should put this contructor for context ?

Comment: In a servlet environment, WEB-INF is not in the classpath, only WEB-INF/classes.so make sure that WEB_INF is in CLASSPATH or move context file to WEB-INF/classes folder and try it will work.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have done that before. I put all spring related xml to WEB_INF/classes i have indtelled it on server . All files correctly appeared in target/../WEB_INF/classes/rightpath.xml but i keep getting same error over and over again. any other suggestions to solve this pain ?